# TortoiseSVN and Putty problems

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

here is the situation:

successfully installed svnserver on a NAS drive accessible by LAN using this tutorial:

http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Step-by-step_guide_to_installing_Subversion_on_ARM-based_Synology_Products

The svn base directory is called svn, and the repo (dummy-name: repo_name) is inside svn.

I've edited the svnserver.conf and passwd files - and created a user as described in "Set Repository Permissions" (I've set anon-write for the sake of testing). From my workstation I try and check out the repo I've created on the NAS, using this format:

svn+ssh://IP_ADDRESS/svn/repo_name

The client attempts to connect, requests a password but fails to establish a connection.

I currently have a couple of hypotheses:

1: Tortoise is having to log in to the NAS itself first
2: I shouldn't be using an IP Address - should I use the drive letter it's mapped to, or the network name of the device?
3: TSVN needs to be configured in some way.

Tortoise is set to use TortoisePlink - when I try and assign Putty to it, it complains about the port (although I can connect and administer using Putty outside of TSVN).

Any ideas?

Comment: will get better attention on serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step by step instructions you link to are for making the repository accessible with a **`svn://`** URL, but you are trying to connect with a **`ssh+svn://`** URL.

When connecting with a `svn://` URL, you need to log in with the username and password configured in the passwd file, i.e. the file referenced in `svnserve.conf` as the `password-db`.

When connecting with a `ssh+svn//` URL, you need to log in with the same username and password as for a SSH session, i.e. the one you [configured in the terminal services](http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_enable/disable_SSH_for_CLI) of the product you are using.

See the section in the SVN book on [svnserve SSH authentication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth) to understand how `ssh+svn://` works. But unless you are planning on making the repository reachable from the outside world over the internet, I doubt you need ssh here.

Comment: The problem was two fold in the end, I'd modified inetd.conf incorrectly, and used the format describe above - thanks for the help